# Journey builder - wait until next Sunday

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have couple of emails which are needs to be sent with particular durations like 2days, 4days which can be achieved by WAIT BY DURATION activity.

But I want my last email to go out the NEXT SUNDAY. How do I achieve this!

I wish there would have been a flow control like,

> #### Wait until next <'Day of the week'>

Comment: You could potentially use a delivery windows that is only on sunday. But then it would always send on sundays. When the journey would trigger on sunday it would immediately send.

Comment: How are you injecting your contacts into the Journey Builder Interaction?

Comment: Basically I am injecting contacts from an external application, which push to Cloudpage and to the API based entry journey.... I am just thinking to use `%%xtdayofweek%%` to capture the ENTRY DAY .. and then calculate the wait days [as here](https://iili.io/JTbbB1.png)  with a combination of Decision split and WAIT activites  ... Do you see any issues with this approach!

Comment: As long as you have this attribute be contact data, you can update the value up until it begins the wait period. Once the wait activity is activated, you cannot change it.  (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for sharing the above link and especially reminding me to add my DE to the Contact model ! ... Please add your above comment as answer, so it may help some one facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have this attribute be contact data, you can update the value up until it begins the wait period. Once the wait activity is activated, you cannot change it.

You can likely update/set this attribute via a SQL query or via Contact Update interaction. This can be done in entry or inside the Journey somewhere.

ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5